# How to clear the buffer in a (char*)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my program I have a `char* buffer` which is being used inside a thread sequence which carries text from one function into another, but the text is different through the run-time in my program. The question that I am asking is, which function can I use to clear the previously used text out of the `char*` ?

For example, I have the following code:

```
int GameUtils::GetText(char *text)
{
    for(int i=0; i<LINES_OF_TEXT; i++)
    {
        if(line[i][0]!=0)
        {
            strcpy(text, line[i]);
            MessageBox(0, text, 0, 0);
            line[i][0]=0; 
            return 1;
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`line` is defined as such: `char GameUtils::line[2][32];`

When the messagebox is output on the screen (while code is executed). I get some random junk characters in the text field. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Also! Note that line is assigned as stated in my previous question.

The function which assigns `line` is:

```
for (int x=0; x<((int)(strlen(szLine)+1)); x++)
{
    if (szLine[x]==' ' || szLine[x]=='\0')
    {
        m=x;
        for (y=0, z=n; z<m; y++, z++)
        {
            line[w][y]=szLine[z];
        }
    n=x+1;
    w++;
    }
}
```

The above function simply takes a parameter `szLine[512]` which is passed from my game interface and splits up the line assorting each space as a new parameter.

As an example, if inside the game the user states the line:

`/msg <player> <message>`

The function would assign each separate word to the `line` variable, respectively.

Such that, after the function is finished. `line` would look like

```
line[0] = /msg
line[1] = <player>
line[2] = <message>
```

So my question overall is as follows. Am I taking the cleaniest/most appropriate approach at this problem? If not, can anyone show me a better way to approach this problem? Also, can anyone explain to me why I am getting junk characters in the `text` parameter when the messagebox executes?

*EDIT*

After viewing the preview of my submitted question; I noticed I have defined `char GameUtils::line[2][32]` as a 2-dimensional array. I had done this earlier to test. I now understand this could have been the cause to my problem. Can anyone suggest me a replacement for this if I don't know the exact amount of parameters that could be inputted into this variable. The user can issue different requests each time like "/help ", "/msg  ", "/whois ", "/create   "...

Comment: How are you allocating the string/buffer?

Comment: line = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);

Comment: A `char*` is not a buffer. It is a pointer into a buffer.

Comment: If you are using C++, you should use an STL `string` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When memory is allocated it isn't zeroed first (at least when using `malloc`, `calloc` - however, does zero memory first).

To clear a buffer in C (rather than C++), you have a few options:

1. Allocate the buffer using `calloc` instead of `malloc`.
2. Use Win32's `ZeroMemory` function
3. Use `memset`, like so: `memset( buffer, 0x00, BUFFER_SIZE );`

However you're clearly using C++, so you should use the standard library and C++ idioms rather than C-style things, that means using `std::string` instead of `char*`, and if you have to use buffers directly then the C++ way of zeroing (or filling) an array or buffer is `std::fill`.

Comment: Thank-you very much! I resorted to using memset() and my problem is now fixed.

Comment: You likely now have the anti-pattern of zeroing the whole buffer before filling it rather than filling it and then adding a terminator.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it is not necessarily a *really* bad anti-pattern

Comment: @Dai We'll have to agree to disagree on that.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would avoid using double dimensional arrays if you can avoid it. Maybe look into std::string:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

As for why a char array might have "random junk" in it, when you allocate a buffer in C++, it always has data in it. You have to manually set the data to 0 if you want it to be empty. So when you first allocate an array, it might be a idea to zero out all the values first.